# Cargar un JList con datos de un array

Tags: java, sql-server, java-swing

Buenas, tengo mi clase `Gestor` con el siguiente código:

```
Class gestor 
{

        private final String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=Persona";
        public final String usuario = "mi_usuario";
        public final String contrasenia = "mi_contraseña";


        ArrayList<Persona> cargarPersonas()
        {
            ArrayList<Persona> personas = new ArrayList<>();

            try
            {
                Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena, usuario, contrasenia);
                Statement st = cn.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Personas");

                while (rs.next())
                {
                    String nombre = rs.getString("nombre");
                    String apellido = rs.getString("apellido");
                    int edad = rs.getInt("edad");

                    Persona p = new Persona(nombre,apellido,edad);
                    personas.add(p);
                }

                rs.close();
                st.close();
                cn.close();

            }catch (SQLException e)
            {
                System.out.println("ERROR : " + e);
            }

            return personas;
        }

}
```

Tengo un `JFrame` llamado `ListadoPersonas` con un `JList` llamado `lstPersonas`. Quisiera poder cargar el mismo con los datos del `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy familiarizado con los `ArrayList`... Pero si estos funcionan igual que un array/vector/arreglo/matriz podrias usar un `for` para llenar la lista de esta manera:

```
    //Debes crear un DefaultListModel
    DefaultListModel lista = new DefaultListModel();
    Jlist.setModel(lista);

    String[] vector = new String[6]; //Por ejemplo (Solo agrego esto para que veas que es un vector)

    for(int i = 0;i < vector.length;i++) {
        lista.addElement(vector[i]);
    }
```

Si el `ArrayList` funciona igual que los vectores solo tienes que adaptar este ejemplo

Comment: Buenas. Logre solucionar mi problema pero olvide dejar una respuesta. Tal cual lo dices tu es una de las formas de hacerlo. Gracias.